# illegal cyclic reference involving error with Spark+Scala combine

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I'm facing ***illegal cyclic reference involving*** error with Spark+Scala combine.

```
Error Ocured during job for '1473170880000000' and Error Message is scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference: illegal cyclic reference involving method srcip
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol$$anonfun$info$3.apply(Symbols.scala:1220)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol$$anonfun$info$3.apply(Symbols.scala:1218)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.lock(Symbols.scala:482)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1218)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.initialize(Symbols.scala:1374)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.privateWithin(Symbols.scala:1169)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.hasAccessBoundary(Symbols.scala:1176)
    at scala.reflect.internal.HasFlags$class.isPublic(HasFlags.scala:111)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.isPublic(Symbols.scala:112)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.ReflectionUtil$$anonfun$2.apply(ReflectionUtil.scala:77)

Error Ocured during job for '1453743420000000' and Error Message is scala.MatchError: <error> (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ErrorType$)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.ReflectionUtil$.returnType(ReflectionUtil.scala:113)
```

This error happens when I try execute more than 1 jobs simultaneously.It smells like multi-threading issue. isn't it ? This error comes when loading data from Cassandra (when perform my first action) or when saving data into Cassandra `rdd.saveToCassandra(...)`

My dependency details

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>dse-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Driver error log [image]

Any suggestions/help on this highly appreciated. has anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: Wer you able to resolve this? Face the same issue at my end too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the issue resolved. My application and spark binaries were built on Scala 2.10.It seems to that Scala 2.10 has reflection/multi thread issue and it is posted as a suggestion on some forums which I gone through.

The fix is, I built my application with Scala 2.11 and used Spark libraries built on 2.11.And the issue disappeared.

**Updated dependencies**

org.apache.spark
        spark-core_2.11
        1.6.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this would help someone.